# python flask-jinja2 remove html characters

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i have this script for meta description in jinja2 :

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ product.description|nl2br|truncate(150) }}" />
```

the problem is output, have html characters :

```
  <meta name="description" content="10.00 $ : Features:
&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;br /&gt;
- Auto-Like
&lt;br /&gt;
- Auto-Comment
&lt;br /&gt;
- Auto-Follow
&lt;br /&gt;
- Auto-Unfollow ALL
&lt;br /&gt;
- Auto-Unfollow People who are not ..." />
```

need output whitout html tags, how can i remove this ?

```
&lt;br,&gt;
```

Comment: where is the duplicate ? i want to solve my problem .... please tell me, where is is ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this one, use `safe`, the documentation is [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe).

> Mark the value as safe which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped.

---

so your code should be:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ product.description | safe | nl2br | truncate(150) }}" />
```

Comment: https://selfmarket.net/product/instagram-bot---like-comment-follow-unfollow-mult-115011384105.html :( not remove the tags

Comment: @selfmarket.net  I'm not sure what you mean from the image, could you explain more?